# Transferring cookies to subdomain located in different Server using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, setcookie, servermanager

How can we pass on cookies to the subdomain if it's on a different server?

Basically, the main domain is on siteground while the subdomain is on softr.io.

I'm using it for the authentication, so when someone logged in to main domain, he/she can access the login session on subdomain as well.

The softr.io haven't ability to add PHP code so I'm left with only using Javascript on the subdomain.

I used the following cookie code:

`setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $expiration_time, '/', $subdomain, true, true);`

It shows the cookie in the Application tab of developer tools but is unable to access in JavaScript by `document.cookie`.

Is anyone here who has already tried this type of task and can guide me.

I did research for a few hours but was unable to figure it out.

Comment: Nitpicking: is it really a subdomain if the parent hostname is on softr.io and the main domain is on another domain?

Answer (score 0):

The 7th argument to `setcookie` is the *HTTP Only* flag.

You’ve set it to `true` which explicitly prevents it from appearing in `document.cookie`.

Turn that security feature off if you want to read it with client-side JS.